# D8: How to perform ajax call in javascript

Tags: ajax, javascript, 8

I'm trying to perform an ajax call from a javascfript file by executing this:

```
            $.ajax({
                url: '/lunapark/ajax/space-invaders/' + score,
                success: function (jsonData) {
                    window.location.replace(jsonData.redirect);
                }
            });
```

But I keep getting:

> GET /lunapark/ajax/space-invaders/90 404 (Not Found)

If I go to the url in my google chrome, it loads and gives me a JSON object, so the page does exist:

```
{"redirect":"\/lunapark\/overview","game":"space-invaders","score":"90"}
```

Now I'm trying this:

```
new Drupal.ajax();
```

But I can't seem to figure it out...

Comment: Hey, I'm not a D8 expert yet, so I could be completely wrong, but I struggled with something _very_ similar recently, and I posted my solution below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of specifying an incorrect datatype in the client call, you fix your route and specify that you return json. Use the _format route key as explained in the [route documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/2092643)

Comment: I added the _format to my routing yml file. I still get a 404 when I put dataType on "json".

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.
You have to use _controller instead of _content:

```
 _controller: '\Drupal\module\Controller\MyController::MyFunction'
```

And add

```
  requirements:
      _format: json
```

In your routing.yml

Comment: Ah, right, I actually mentioned that first as well, but then removed it again. _content is specific to a response that should be shown in the main content block, it can result in weird behavior when using for something else.

Comment: I've seen that mistake a few times, if you can think of something that would have helped you to figure this out faster, please make suggestions on the documentation, examples, or whatever you looked at when working on your code.

Comment: Berdir, I looked into core combined with D8 API. In the end it makes sense...